# Select records order by count of another table not retrieving correct count in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

In mysql db,i'm having two tables `book` and `ratingtable`.

book table has three fields `ID,uniqueid,Title`

ratingtable has three fields `Book_ID,userid,rating`

I need a query which retrieve records `group by id` (of book table) and `order by count(rating)` (of ratingtable).

I tried a query like this:

```
SELECT book.ID,book.Title,COUNT(ratingtable.rating) AS views
FROM book LEFT JOIN ratingtable ON book.ID = ratingtable.book_ID
GROUP BY book.ID
ORDER BY views DESC
```

But for three values it displays wrong count value. I dunno what happens.

**EDIT:**
ratingtable:

[image]

book:

[image]

Here the answer[count(rating)] should be 1 for all. But it displays

[image]
Help me to resolve this.

Comment: Show us table data and the result you get, and describe what's wrong with it. (I can't find anything wrong with your statement.)

Comment: What do you mean by "it displays wrong count value"? Do you have a book that has been rated by, say, three users, but the query gives you a count of one rating for that book?

Comment: @jarlh check my EDIT, given some sample content. check my query..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight check my EDIT, given some sample content.

Comment: Your query works perfectly with your data on ideone ([link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/597c2/2)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry for what i have done... I have given you wrong bok table. updated my table. `id` is not unique. there is another `uniqueid` in my table. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This is my actual table. I think `uniqueid` is the reason for my query not working. Help me out.

Comment: Is (1, aaa, 100) considered to be the same book as (1, aaa, 101), or is it a different book?

Comment: @jarlh same book, but it has unique id (in library we have book access number for each individual book na).

Comment: whats with SELCT t1.ID, COUNT(ratingtable.Rating) as views FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID from book) t1 LEFT JOIN ratingtable ON t1.ID=ratingtable.book_ID ORDER BY views DESC

Answer (score 1):

The result you're getting is actually quite correct, given that your book id's are not unique. But, to get the count you want you can use a subquery to first group the books, and then doing the counting:

```
SELECT b2.ID, b2.Title,COUNT(ratingtable.rating) AS views
FROM 
    (SELECT b1.id, b1.title FROM Book b1 Group by b1.id, b1.title) b2 
LEFT JOIN ratingtable ON b2.ID = ratingtable.book_ID
GROUP BY b2.ID, b2.Title
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by both book id and title.

```
SELECT book.ID, book.Title, COUNT(ratingtable.rating) AS views
FROM book LEFT JOIN ratingtable ON book.ID = ratingtable.book_ID
GROUP BY book.ID, book.Title
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Or use correlated sub-query to count:

```
select distinct book.ID,
                book.Title,
                (select count(*) from ratingtable
                 where book.ID = ratingtable.book_ID) as views
from book
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. first query you mentioned is not working. But the second query is working as what i need. Thank you again.